# How to exclude filetype in autocmd using Neovim's Lua API?

Tags: neovim, autocmd, init.lua

Translating [this excellent Vimscript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12018552/5437918) for creating an autocmd that applies certain options only to the focused window into Lua, I have the following:

```lua
local focused_window_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('CursorLine', { clear = true })
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'VimEnter', 'WinEnter', 'BufWinEnter'}, {
  callback = function()
    vim.wo.cursorline     = true
    vim.wo.colorcolumn    = '100'
    vim.wo.relativenumber = true
  end,
  group = focused_window_group,
  pattern = '*',
})
```

Which works as I expect. With the `cursorline`, `colorcolumn` and `relativenumber` only applying to my focused window split. However an unintended side effect of this was that now Vim help texts also have these options activated whenever I enter them. And when I leave the help window, its `relativenumber` column disappears, which jarringly ends up shifting the text in the help window. Therefore I'd like to be able to exclude buffers with `filetype=help` from my above autocmd.

Using [this Vimscript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60338380/5437918) as an example, I tried to augment the `pattern` key in the passed options table as:

```lua
pattern = {'*', vim.bo.filetype ~= "help"}
```

But when reloading this change, I get the error: `Invalid 'pattern' item: expected String, got Boolean` when starting Neovim. This makes sense since the documentation for `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd()` says the value for the `pattern` key is `(string|array) optional: pattern(s) to match literally |autocmd-pattern|.` Wrapping the filetype conditional check in single quotes suppresses the `Invalid 'pattern' item` error, but does not remove help files from activating the autocmd.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Another option you could do is set the settings you want in your `init.lua` unconditionally, and then create the file `.after/ftplugin/help.lua` that *un*sets those options. e.g.:

```lua
-- ~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/help.lua
vim.wo.cursorline = false
vim.wo.colorcolumn = ''
vim.wo.relativenumber = false
```

Comment: Interesting. I might give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I came up with a workaround, which I'm not entirely satisfied with, since it doesn't make my intentions as clear. But it does now behave as I want it to. The workaround is to wrap the `vim.wo` settings in the `callback` function in a conditional block that checks the filetype, like so:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ 'VimEnter', 'WinEnter', 'BufWinEnter'}, {
  callback = function()
    if vim.bo.filetype ~= 'help' then
      vim.wo.cursorline     = true
      vim.wo.colorcolumn    = '100'
      vim.wo.relativenumber = true
    end
  end,
  group = focused_window_group,
  pattern = '*',
})
```

This leaves the help text windows unaffected, i.e. they don't display `relativenumber` nor any `number` column, which how they are by default even if you were to set `vim.o.number = true` in your `init.lua`. Later on, shall I find other filetypes I'd like to omit these autocmd actions on, I could just add them into the conditional check.

Ideally, I'd still like to know if it's possible to add this constraint to the `pattern` key instead. So better answers are still welcome.

Comment: Vim’s autocommands don’t support sophisticated pattern contraints (`:help {aupat}`). Conditionals are the answer, and I don’t really see anything wrong with that?

Comment: Great thanks for clarifying.